# Chat room control should to used

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm would like to ask you about the Skype's chat message block, what kind of control they used?

I just want to create a chat room like a skype chating tab, But I don't know for sure to used which control easy to manage, for skype like TextBox or ListBox to store message sent.

Comment: A `TextBox` with `MultiLine` enabled would do...?

Comment: This is not really a programming question - you should try and write a control that does what you want and then ask questions when you hit some functionality you can't implement.

Comment: If I used textbox, How to store File when they send file, for skype

[Author space filename space datetime] looking like a one record, does textbox can input file icon in it?

Answer (score 0):

For the Skype chat box:

use a rich textbox or a multiline text box.

For creating a chat application:

Break it up into bits.

If you want a tabbed chat application the first thing you'll need to implement is the chat server and client.

[Here's a decent simple WPF chat application tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/190932/Simple-chat-application-in-WPF-and-C) you can look into.

And then after it's all created and working add a tab control and work with that.

Comment: If I used textbox, How to store File when they send file, for skype

[Author space filename space datetime] looking like a one record, does textbox can input file icon in it?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Textbox for each message which would allow you to have more control over the positioning. But a non-clickable Listbox would be good too. in the end it's your artistic choice

Comment: I saw one tutorial about chat also, they using RichTextBox, and Richtextbox can put image file and control within as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use List that contains listItem that contains Paragraph or TextBlock
this way you can use different fonts color ans style for the sender and the receiver, like this:

```
            <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn >
                    <ListBoxItem Width="85" Height="15">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="my content here"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```